# lambda and TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to use the lambda function.

```
import random
from string import ascii_letters

choice = lambda x: x[int(random()* len(x))]

print(choice("azerty"))
```

But I get an error :

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I'm confused. Can you help me ? Thanks.

Comment: what do you expect `random()` to do?

Comment: In general, lambda expressions are not meant to be assigned to variables. You should use `def` for that

Answer (score 0):

Use this. [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.random) is a module which contains a function called `random`. You can use it by doing `random.random()`.

```
choice = lambda x: x[int(random.random()* len(x))]
```

---

If you want you `random()` directly then use this.

```
from random import random
choice = lambda x: x[int(random()* len(x))]
```